# Side by side tables layout issues when different heights

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Using SSRS and exporting to PDF, I have two tables side by side (can see the layout in the below image link). The right table is a single column that may be shorter or longer than the left table. If it's shorter the layout looks fine, but if it's longer then it only takes up half the width on the following pages. The problem also occurs if the textbox above the right table contains a lot of text, pushing the right table down further.

Is there a way to get the rows of the second table to take up the full width on those pages instead of just half?

[Table Layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTRZt.png)

EDIT: Added a drawing example of the printout.

Also, Table 1 has dynamic columns. It will always be less than half the page width, but it means in the layout that Table 2 and the above textboxes adjust as the columns expand. However, when table 1 is not there (like on the second page) they adjust back to where they are in the layout (hence why Table 2 and the containing rectangle moved back to the left on the page break.

What I need is for the textboxes and Table 2 to wrap and take up the full width when they go longer than Table 1.

[Printout Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXmzo.png)

EDIT 2: Adding screenshots [Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4srp.png) [Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7WgR.png) [Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeSJw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Place each section in a rectangle, so in your case probably a rectangle for table 1 another for the two text boxes and another for table 2. Also set the `ConsumContainerWhitespace' property to`True` in the report properties.

Hopefully this will solve the issue, if not please show a sample of the actually output.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what is actually happening, it's hard to solve without more info.